# Use of na.locf function (zoo package) with .SD in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I am trying to fill out all NA's excluding the first two NA's for cols 1 and 4 and three NA's for cols 2 and 3 with most recent non-NA value . Here is my data and code:

```
  hh<-structure(list(ka = c(NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
        kb = c(NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, NA), gc = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 6, NA, NA, NA), hc = c(NA, NA, 8, NA, 
        NA, NA, 4, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("ka", "kb", "gc", "hc"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


library(zoo) #na.locf
library(data.table)

setDT(hh)[,`:=`(ka=c(NA,NA,na.locf(ka)),kb=c(NA,NA,NA,na.locf(kb)),gc=c(NA,NA,NA,na.locf(gc)),hc=c(NA,NA,na.locf(hc)))][]
    ka kb gc hc
 1: NA NA NA NA
 2: NA NA NA NA
 3:  2 NA NA  8
 4:  2  2  3  8
 5:  2  2  3  8
 6:  3  2  3  8
 7:  3  3  6  4
 8:  3  3  6  4
 9:  3  3  6  4
10:  3  3  6  4
```

However, I am looking for use of `lapply` with `.SD` as I have more than two columns for each type.  Is this possible?

Comment: this will also give the same result `na.locf(hh, na.rm = F)`

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar  It would work, but if there are mixed class, I would suspect the output to change the class to 'character'

Comment: Thanks @VeerendraGadekar

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try

```
 setDT(hh)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) na.locf(x, na.rm=FALSE))]
```

Or use `set`

```
  for(j in seq_along(hh)){
    set(hh, i=NULL, j=j, value= na.locf(hh[[j]], na.rm=FALSE))
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `setnafill`, available from `data.table >= 1.12.3`:

```
setnafill(hh, type = "locf")
hh
#    ka kb gc hc
#  1 NA NA NA NA
#  2 NA NA NA NA
#  3  2 NA NA  8
#  4  2  2  3  8
#  5  2  2  3  8
#  6  3  2  3  8
#  7  3  3  6  4
#  8  3  3  6  4
#  9  3  3  6  4
# 10  3  3  6  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `lapply`.  This is sufficient:

```
DT <- as.data.table(hh)
DT[, na.locf(.SD, na.rm = FALSE)]
```

giving:

```
    ka kb gc hc
 1: NA NA NA NA
 2: NA NA NA NA
 3:  2 NA NA  8
 4:  2  2  3  8
 5:  2  2  3  8
 6:  3  2  3  8
 7:  3  3  6  4
 8:  3  3  6  4
 9:  3  3  6  4
10:  3  3  6  4
```

This will also work:

```
DT[, lapply(.SD, na.locf0)]
```