# Filling NAs forward/backward with data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I'd like to fill NAs with either forward or backward value filling with data.table in R. I saw a few posts explaining how to do it, but still have some trouble for multiple columns.

Say, I have a data table DT with three columns ("a", "b", "c")

I tried the following code but did not work

```
var.names <- c("a", "b", "c")
DT[, var.names := na.locf(list(var.names)), with = FALSE]
```

or

```
DT[, var.names, roll = TRUE, with = FALSE]
```

Comment: `DT[, var.names := lapply(.SD, na.locf), .SDcols = var.names]`?

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491976/use-of-na-locf-function-zoo-package-with-sd-in-data-table/

Comment: Thanks for the help. I read those posts, and my question is actually how to apply it to multiple columns by referring the column names. I think using lapply definitely is the solution.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491976/ is quite helpful